# How can I make the output be with 2 numbers after ,?

Tags: python, decimal

I have the lines

```py
x=int(input("Ievadi temperaturas skaitlisko vertibu:"))
d=(x*1.8)-459.672
```

and the output is:

```
print("Konvertejot temperaturu ",x,"°K, no Kelvina skalas uz Farenheita skalu, iegust",d," °F")
```

I've tried many things like {.2f}, making the numbers float(), i've tried round(), .format.
Nothing seems to work to make the result a `xx,yy`. Instead I get `xx,yyyyyyy...` etc.

Where should I put the rounding object? Also it should be easy, beginner level. I've recently had to start learning python.

Thank you

Comment: using f string, `f"Value is: {d:.2f}"`

Comment: its as simple as this `d_round = round(d,2)`.  Not sure why round didnt work for you ?!?

Answer (score 1):

You can round the number by doing (use steps when programming):

```
d = (x*1.8)-459.672
d_rounded = round(d, 2)  # round to two decimals
```

To print, use:

```
print("Konvertejot temperaturu", x, "°K, no Kelvina skalas uz Farenheita skalu, iegust", d_rounded, " °F")
```

but I would prefer an f-String for better readability:

```
print(f"Konvertejot temperaturu {x}°K, no Kelvina skalas uz Farenheita skalu, iegust {d_rounded}°F")
```

Comment: It's not working :(
I added d_rounded=round(d,2) in the next line after d=... and wrote the code as you said in your comment.

Comment: @FakeCode whats the error? It works on my side. Maybe help yourself and print it out stepwise first: print(d) and print(d_rounded). To see, if that works first.